# Downgrade windows phone 10 to 8.1

Tags: insider-preview, recovery-tool

I have Nokia Lumia 620 and installed the windows insider and it wont download any updates via internet. So I thought roll back to windows 8.1

The problem is it needs to download 1.5 gb and I have 512 kbps internet.

So I used fiddler and downloaded the 1.5gb file using download manager.
It's some "signed.ffu" file.

Now the problem how to use that ffu file to install in windows phone.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the location of my file as created by the Windows Device Recovery Tool.

"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Packages\Products\rm-821\RM821_3051.50009.1424.0027_RETAIL_eu_euro1_342_27_451764_prd_signed.ffu

rm-821 is the phone model I have (930) so if you put your FFU in the equivilent directory the tool should pick it up

Comment: Ok I found many files in the directory. Shall I replace the RM846_3058.50000.1425.0001_RETAIL_im_india_233_01_450672_prd_signed.ffu.tmp   with RM846_3058.50000.1425.0001_RETAIL_im_india_233_01_450672_prd_signed.ffu or shall I remove all the files and put RM846_3058.50000.1425.0001_RETAIL_im_india_233_01_450672_prd_signed.ffu..?

Comment: Just the file you manually downloaded.  Ideally they should be called the same thing